# ForEach not working in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So basically I want to migrate my data from Firebase Realtime Database to Cloud Firestore.
This is what I've been trying for now:

```
bot.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  // const receivedTimestamp = Date.now()
  const telegramText = req.body
    && req.body.message
    && req.body.message.chat
    && req.body.message.chat.id
    && req.body.message.from
    && req.body.message.from.first_name

  if (telegramText && req.body.message === '/migrate') {
const snapAllUsersData = await admin.database().ref(`/Data/users/`).once("value").then(async function (allUsers: any) {
  let usersMigrated= 0
  allUsers.forEach((eachUser: any) => {
    usersMigrated= usersMigrated + 1
    const currentName = eachUser.val().name
    const currentCountry = eachUser.val().country 
                    
    admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(currentName.toLowerCase()).set({ "name": currentName, "country": currentCountry }, { merge: true }).then(() => {
      console.log(`${usersMigrated} | ${currentName} | ${currentCountry}`)
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  });
  console.log(`${usersMigrated} migrated successfully`)
}).catch((errGettingData) => {
  console.log(errGettingData)
  return
})

})
```

There are no logs in the Firebase Console Either :(

Similar code works in Node.JS projects which I run on my GCP VM. SNot working in here....

Database Structure:

```
Data:
  users:
    User1:
      name: "Dharmaraj",
      country: "IN"
    User8:
      name: "Qwerty",
      country: "US"
```

PS: there is no issue in path and any case sensitivity issue

**EDIT:**
So now I ran the very SAME CODE in a NODE.JS project without Cloud Functions.... Just ran it in local terminal and it worked buttery smooth and all data got migrated in within 5 seconds...

Comment: @PeterHaddad correction made* Had copied the line from other project... It's allUsers

Comment: add a screenshot of ur firebase realtime database

Comment: @PeterHaddad sorry that contains real names and contact.. can I type out the structure in the Question with imaginary names?

Comment: @PeterHaddad I typed out DB structure... But again Path and case sensitivity is not the issue :)

Comment: @PeterHaddad  I ran the very SAME CODE in a NODE.JS project without Cloud Functions.... Just ran it in local terminal and it worked buttery smooth and all data got migrated in within 5 seconds... Though I will still wait if there is any update on why it is not working in Cloud Functions

Comment: I don't see where you've exported an actual Cloud Function for deployment.  Without that, nothing will run.  If you do have a definition, please edit the question to show the entire function code that doesn't work the way you expect.  We should be able to duplicate the issue using the information you provide here.

Comment: @DougStevenson `"exported an actual Cloud Function for deployment. "` I did not understand this ?? oh or maybe I forgot to mention the trigger over here. This gets triggered by Telegram Bot Message :) Though it was deployed on Cloud Functions!!

2nd time when I ran it without cloud functions, in my GCP VM it did the job. oh and I used Discord bot message as trigger for the 2nd time but that is not an issue.. Code does reach that part ... I used the same code and it worked outside of cloud functions.

Comment: The code still isn't showing a cloud functions trigger.  This can't possibly be the entire code.  You need to provide a minimal, complete example and explain what it's doing that's different than what you expect. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DougStevenson that is because I am not using one! I am sorry if I got confused anything that works in Cloud Functions are cloud functions! I am not using any database trigger onCreate() or so. Issue is when I deploy that piece of code to cloud functions it wont work!

Comment: At which step it fails? Is there anything in CF logs? I would say add more logging to isolate the issue.

Comment: @EmilGi nothing in logs but only Process finished in xxxx ms. Like usual cloud functions does after finishing. But no console.log() statements work -_-

Comment: As Doug asked, please update your question with a simple reproduction steps so that we can debug it further.

Comment: Are you still dealing with this issue @Dharmaraj? I'm not sure whether it's the same problem or not but there have been a few times when I use array.forEach in firebase functions where it seems to leave the flow of execution. In other words, the whole function just exits/returns while forEach is STILL RUNNING. Incredibly frustrating.

Comment: @sambecker hey I think I found the correct way, but can you tell me what are you trying to do in the forEach. Or I think it'll be better to create a new question on stackoverflow. I use Promise.all() now

Comment: First of all @Dharmaraj I switched my whole application to return `Promise.all` at the end of every function and that greatly increased the stability. As for `forEach`, I've run into many problems and switched to `for (const item of element)` loops instead. One specific issue I recall having was creating a `firestore` batch and using a forEach to populate it before calling `commit`. What I saw is that firebase was calling commit before the forEach loop finished! And I wasn't using `await` btw, which I know you can't do!

Comment: @sambecker yeah forEach is not async, so JS won't wait for it to complete. Instead you can use forEach to push those pormises to an array and the use `return Promise.all(thatArrayOfPromises)`

Comment: That’s what I was doing @Dharmaraj and it still didn’t work, so stopped using `forEach` all together. Even for generating promises (in Google’s node environment) it was behaving erratically.